# Salvar input em um Arquivo txt HTML e PHP

Tags: php, html

Olá, estou tentando salvar as informações digitadas no Input do HTML em txt. Já tenho meu código que parece estar funcionando.. Porém não está criando o txt.
Alguém consegue descobrir o pq?

Esse é o form, dentro do body:

```html
<form name="web_form" id="web_form" method="post" action="teste.php">
        <p><label>Enter name: </label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></p>
        <p><label>Enter email: </label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name=s1″ id="s1″ value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Esse é o PHP:

```php
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fp = fopen("formdata.txt", "a");
$savestring = $name . "," . $email . "n";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Pode ser um problema de permissão de escrita na pasta. a variável $fp está como false?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas acredito que não. Testei na área de trabalho e tb nem foi..

Comment: no meu teste funcionou perfeitamente